# Installing Wine with aptitude

Tags: 12.04, apt, wine, aptitude

I'm trying to install Wine on Ubuntu Precise. I'm used to using `aptitude` for package management, so I tried to use that to install Wine. When I do that, I'm told I have to resolve dependencies that end up leaving me with 21 packages being uninstalled! However, when I try to install with `apt-get`, it appears to work fine.

What's going on? Will it work right if I install Wine through `apt-get`? Will it break `aptitude`? Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it is that "aptitude" actually is running something of an equivalent of "apt-get autoremove" before downloading and installing wine. Its trying to remove dependencies first which it thinks is no longer in use but somehow its causing interference with installation of wine.

"apt-get" on the other hand doesn't require this. It'll only remove dependencies which are not in use if you explicitly tell it by running "apt-get autoremove".

"aptitude" no doubt is a bit feature rich than "apt-get", but if you get the desired result through "apt-get", I see no reason not to use it.

And in my opinion, "apt-get" shouldn't break "aptitude".

Comment: Unfortunately, I thought of that too - `apt-get autoremove` doesn't find anything to get rid of. The thing is that the "conflict" (?) doesn't happen until I ask to install wine. Did you watch the screen recording?

Comment: what's the problem with installing through "apt-get"?

Comment: Nothing except that I was worried it would break `aptitude` or something. I as much wanted to know _why_ the problem was happening as how to fix it.

Comment: I tried installing with `apt-get` and everything's working fine. I'd still love to know what was going on, but the current question is no longer outstanding.

Answer (score 0):

`aptitude` remembers which packages were explicitly requested and which were only installed due to dependencies. It will automatically uninstall packages which were not explicitly requested when they are no longer needed.

`apt-get` treats packages requested explicitly and their dependencies the same.

So better use `aptitude`, this helps to keep your system clean.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. I can't install wine using aptitude. Watch the recording.

Comment: Downvote: Sorry, but this is incorrect, both remember packages installed as dependencies, but apt-get will only remove them when asked to do it. And OP problem is not related to this, aptitude wants to remove 20 packages because a dependency needed by them is absent.